# Wordpress ecommerce functionality with custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, shopping-cart, cart

I am new to wordpress, just worked on 2 sites and I have new challange! now I have to create custom post types as a product because I already have old system with me. I wanted to convert existing offline course products from core php site to wordpress for that I have to create courses as custom posts because these courses will be in two semesters and they have conditional displays according to date.
So can you please suggest me how my approach should be ( I am thinking of creating custom post use it as product and list it with add to cart button and connect with any available plugin which will handle rest of the checkout process with admin functionalities and then I will build the other things arround it  )

Note: Actually I am worried about how to list the products/courses per semester if semester is ended then just list them otherwise list will have add to cart function, how can I add the late fee for registration (if applies) and one time registration fee, also I need to add donation amount separately can this be taken care by anything common.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the woocommerce then you should import your courses as products (post type).
That will make every course you have as a product then you can update the postmeta of this product to the various values of this product like price
So first step is install woocommerce plugin then loop the courses you have on [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).
After that in the same loop you should add post meta for every post you inserted.